# AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'in_dir'

Tags: python, class, attributeerror

Here is my code of Reader class and its child class

```
import os
import sys

class Reader:
    def __init__(self, in_dir, ext='txt'):
        self.in_dir = in_dir
        self.ext = ext

class TextFileReader(Reader):
    def __init__(self, in_dir, ext):
        Reader.__init__(in_dir, ext)

    def process(self, doc):

        file_name = os.path.join(in_dir, doc.file_name + "." + ext)
        with open(file_name,'r') as file_to_read:
            doc.set_document_text(file_to_read.read())
```

Here is what I do for testing this class:

```
from document import *
from reader import * 

file_name = 'doc1'
in_dir = '/Users/wenzhe.yang/NLP_work/sample_data/'

tfr = TextFileReader(in_dir, ext='txt')
doc = Document(file_name)
tfr.process(doc)
```

I don't know what happened with my class module, everything is normal, when I call the class from another file for testing the error came up like this:

```
    AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
~/NLP_Work/sema4_deid_prep_rev 2/prep/test.py in 
      6 in_dir = '/Users/wenzhe.yang/NLP_work/sample_data/'
      7 
----> 8 tfr = TextFileReader(in_dir, ext='txt')
      9 doc = Document(file_name)
     10 tfr.process(doc)

~/NLP_Work/sema4_deid_prep_rev 2/prep/reader.py in __init__(self, in_dir, ext)
     15 class TextFileReader(Reader):
     16     def __init__(self, in_dir, ext):
---> 17         Reader.__init__(in_dir, ext)
     18 
     19     def process(self, doc):

~/NLP_Work/sema4_deid_prep_rev 2/prep/reader.py in __init__(self, in_dir, ext)
      6 class Reader:
      7     def __init__(self, in_dir, ext='txt'):
----> 8         self.in_dir = in_dir
      9         self.ext = ext
     10 


AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'in_dir'
```

Any idea about why the attribute error here?  I've been frustrated for days, because they are so simple but still got error and I cannot find out why.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You also passed `in_dir` and `ext` instead of `self.in_dir` and `self.ext` in `TextFileReader.process` method.
It should be fixed to:

```py
def process(self, doc):
    file_name = os.path.join(self.in_dir, doc.file_name + "." + self.ext)
    with open(file_name,'r') as file_to_read:
        doc.set_document_text(file_to_read.read())
```

Answer (score 0):

When calling the superclass' constructor, you should also pass `self` to it:

```py
class TextFileReader(Reader):
    def __init__(self, in_dir, ext):
        Reader.__init__(self, in_dir, ext)
        # Here ---------^
```